# Alexa Smart Home Response with Custom Message

Tags: iot, alexa-skills-kit

I have an Alexa Smart Home Skill and I would like to be able to return a custom response message with certain requests. I've tried using:

```
{
    "payload": { "message": "My custom message" }
}
```

as well as replacing `message` with `caption`, but neither seem to work. Each time, i get the default `ok` response. Does anybody know if this is possible for a Smart Home Skill? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, in Smart Home Skill, we cannot add custom response from Alexa. There are fixed set of [responses build into Alexa](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-smarthome/issues/19) as of January of 2018.

If you are not using Smart Home Skill, you can make Alexa speak custom responses.

Comment: Thanks @Aarth, this is the conclusion that I came to as well. Do you work for Amazon? Do you have any idea if such a feature is on the roadmap?

Comment: No, I don't work with Amazon. However, I have contacted them for some query. If my answer was helpful upvote and accept it.

Comment: The link you provided references error responses, which is useful. However, I was asking for success responses. Do you have a link regarding that as well?

Comment: Currently Alexa will only respond with "OK"

Comment: That's what I've experienced as well. Was hoping to see some formal documentation about it, some things like that are hard to find.